Drag effect for three js fiber
im trying to build florplan website but only 2D version,i decided to use three js fiber and Vectors ,then I filled the area inside the square I made of Vectors by triangles.Now last step,i need to add ability to drag and move that vectors, here is my code,
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Vector3, BufferGeometry, BufferAttribute } from "three";
import * as THREE from 'three'

const Example7 = () => {
  const vectors = [
    new Vector3(2, 1, 3),
    new Vector3(2, 2, 3),
    new Vector3(2, 2, 4),
    new Vector3(2, 2, 5),
    new Vector3(2, 1, 5),
    new Vector3(2, 0, 5),
    new Vector3(2, 0, 4),
    new Vector3(2, 0, 3)
  ];

  const lineRef = useRef();

  const generateVertices = () => {
    const vertices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < vectors.length - 1; i++) {
      vertices.push(vectors[i].x, vectors[i].y, vectors[i].z);
      vertices.push(vectors[i + 1].x, vectors[i + 1].y, vectors[i + 1].z);
    }
    vertices.push(
      vectors[vectors.length - 1].x,
      vectors[vectors.length - 1].y,
      vectors[vectors.length - 1].z
    );
    vertices.push(vectors[0].x, vectors[0].y, vectors[0].z);
    return new Float32Array(vertices);
  };

  const geometry = new BufferGeometry();
  geometry.setAttribute("position", new BufferAttribute(generateVertices(), 3));

  // Function to calculate triangle vertices dynamically
  const calculateTriangleVertices = () => {
    const triangle1Vertices = [
      vectors[1].x, vectors[1].y, vectors[1].z,
      vectors[2].x, vectors[2].y, vectors[2].z,
      vectors[0].x, vectors[0].y, vectors[0].z,
    ];
    const triangle2Vertices = [
      vectors[7].x, vectors[7].y, vectors[7].z,
      vectors[2].x, vectors[2].y, vectors[2].z,
      vectors[0].x, vectors[0].y, vectors[0].z
    ];
    const triangle3Vertices = [
      vectors[7].x, vectors[7].y, vectors[7].z,
      vectors[2].x, vectors[2].y, vectors[2].z,
      vectors[6].x, vectors[6].y, vectors[6].z
    ];
    const triangle4Vertices = [
      vectors[2].x, vectors[2].y, vectors[2].z,
      vectors[3].x, vectors[3].y, vectors[3].z,
      vectors[4].x, vectors[4].y, vectors[4].z
    ];
    const triangle5Vertices = [
      vectors[2].x, vectors[2].y, vectors[2].z,
      vectors[4].x, vectors[4].y, vectors[4].z,
      vectors[6].x, vectors[6].y, vectors[6].z
    ];
    const triangle6Vertices = [
      vectors[5].x, vectors[5].y, vectors[5].z,
      vectors[4].x, vectors[4].y, vectors[4].z,
      vectors[6].x, vectors[6].y, vectors[6].z
    ];
    return {
      triangle1Vertices,
      triangle2Vertices,
      triangle3Vertices,
      triangle4Vertices,
      triangle5Vertices,
      triangle6Vertices
    };
  };

  const { triangle1Vertices, triangle2Vertices,triangle3Vertices,triangle4Vertices,triangle5Vertices,triangle6Vertices } = calculateTriangleVertices();

  const triangle1Geometry = new BufferGeometry();
  triangle1Geometry.setAttribute("position", new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(triangle1Vertices), 3));

  const triangle2Geometry = new BufferGeometry();
  triangle2Geometry.setAttribute("position", new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(triangle2Vertices), 3));

  const triangle3Geometry = new BufferGeometry();
  triangle3Geometry.setAttribute("position", new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(triangle3Vertices), 3));

  const triangle4Geometry = new BufferGeometry();
  triangle4Geometry.setAttribute("position", new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(triangle4Vertices), 3));

  const triangle5Geometry = new BufferGeometry();
  triangle5Geometry.setAttribute("position", new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(triangle5Vertices), 3));

  const triangle6Geometry = new BufferGeometry();
  triangle6Geometry.setAttribute("position", new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(triangle6Vertices), 3));

  return (
    <div className="relative top-100 h-screen w-full">
      <Canvas>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <OrbitControls />

        <line ref={lineRef}>
          <primitive object={geometry} />
          <lineBasicMaterial attach="material" color="red" />
        </line>

        <mesh>
          <primitive object={triangle1Geometry} />
          <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="green" transparent opacity={1} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
        </mesh>

        <mesh>
          <primitive object={triangle2Geometry} />
          <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="green" transparent opacity={1} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
        </mesh>

        <mesh>
          <primitive object={triangle3Geometry} />
          <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="green" transparent opacity={1} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
        </mesh>

        <mesh>
          <primitive object={triangle4Geometry} />
          <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="green" transparent opacity={1} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
        </mesh>

        <mesh>
          <primitive object={triangle5Geometry} />
          <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="green" transparent opacity={1} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
        </mesh>

        <mesh>
          <primitive object={triangle6Geometry} />
          <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="green" transparent opacity={1} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
        </mesh>

        {vectors.map((vector, index) => (
          <mesh key={index} position={vector}>
            <boxGeometry args={[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color="gray" />
          </mesh>
        ))}
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example7;


`
please help and thanks in advance:)
I tried to use 3d shapes instead of vectors but I failed
